# Kendo UI Grid: Dynamic addition of fields in the model

Tags: model, grid, kendo-ui

I'm trying to dynamically generate a model for grid:

```
$(this).kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
    data: _data,
        schema: {
            model: _model
        }
    }
})
```

That's how I create the model

```
var _model = eval('kendo.data.Model.define({ id: "id", fields: { MyField: { editable: false } } });');
```

But the grid ignores all the model settings. But if I do so:

```
var _model = kendo.data.Model.define({ id: "id", fields: { MyField: { editable: false } } });
```

All works.
In both cases, the objects are exactly the same, but in one case, everything is normal, and in another - all settings are ignored. Why?

Comment: Both seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/x5Bdh/ Which version of KendoUI are you using?

Answer (score 0):

try to assign value to a variable in eval. 
i.e.
var _model;
eval('_model = kendo.data.Model.define({ id: "id", fields: { MyField: { editable: false } } });');